# Dynamically add linq where statements

Tags: c#

I'm using Mock Data for prototyping something.
I want to simulate a search on different fields. Not all search parameters must be filled.
I would like to filter my Mock Data with the set filters, but I can't seem to make it work.

This is what I have:
A list of modules with some properties. like ID, Name Code, etc.

```
var AllModules = new List<Module>{
  new Module{Id=1, Name="MockName", Code="ModCode", Active:false},
  new Module{Id=2, Name="MockNameFoo", Code="ModCodeFoo", Active:true}
 }
```

Then I would like to add where clauses depending on the filters properties.

```
class Filter{
    string Text {get;set;}
    bool? IsActive {get;set;}
}
```

then I would like to filter the list depending if the filters are set or not, so I have tried:

```
public <List<Module> GetModules(Filter modulesQuery)
{

  var query = from module in AllModules.AsQueryable()
                        select module;
  if (modulesQuery.IsActive.HasValue)
  {
    query.Where(x => x.Active== modulesQuery.IsActive.value);
  }
  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulesQuery.Text))
  {
    query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(modulesQuery.Text,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)||
        x.Code.Contains(modulesQuery.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
  }
 return query.ToList();
}
```

This is however not working and always returns me the complete list. It ignores all the where clauses, event thou I see that it goes to each if statements and "adds" them.

I don't know if this is completely wrong? I had the same thing when I first had the code with predicate Builder.
BTW this is a .netCore  project... but I don't think that make a difference here.

Thank you

Comment: Notice the Query = query.Where in the targeted dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign the query in your `if` blocks back to the local variable. LINQ doesn't mutate the original query, but "adds" to it. As you're not assigning it, the return value from the `Where()` calls doesn't end up being used.

```
public List<Module> GetModules(Filter modulesQuery)
{

  var query = from module in AllModules.AsQueryable()
                        select module;
  if (modulesQuery.IsActive.HasValue)
  {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Active== modulesQuery.IsActive.value);
  }

  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulesQuery.Text))
  {
    query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(modulesQuery.Text,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)||
        x.Code.Contains(modulesQuery.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
  }

  return query.ToList();
}
```

Comment: Oh man! Thx a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try assigning the result back to the query variable.

I don't know the rest of the implementation, but I would recommend that you leave it as an IQueryable. So you're able to manipulate it more without persisting it at this stage.

Only use a ToList/ToArray when you really need to.

```
public IQueryable<Module> GetModules(Filter modulesQuery)
{

    var query = from module in AllModules.AsQueryable()
                        select module;

    if (modulesQuery.IsActive.HasValue)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Active== modulesQuery.IsActive.value);
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(modulesQuery.Text))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Name.Contains(modulesQuery.Text,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)||
        x.Code.Contains(modulesQuery.Text, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)));
    }
    return query;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Where` returns an `IEnumerable` of the values you've filtered on. It does not mutate your original collection.

Example:

```
var filteredList = query.Where(x => x.Active== modulesQuery.IsActive.value);
```

Right now, you're just ignoring the return value from `Where`, which I feel like should be a compiler warning but whatever.